# MapStruct map field to Map<String,Object> mapped by field name

Tags: mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to provide bean mapping between different systems, and I have reached a point where the only way to map a specific property is to add it as a Map entry to the target object with the field name as key.

I can do this using a very long expression where I set the entire map using guava ImmutableMap builder, but is there a more elegant and safe way of providing this mapping? Setter method would expect two parameters in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not support in MapStruct. There is already an open feature request [#1075](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1075) for support like this.

Comment: Thank you, I will be watching the issue, also found [#1218](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1218) there.